Identify western movie with an Indian fight reused in the Time Tunnel
I am asking what movie was the source of the (color) scene of a battle between Apaches and US Cavalry in the episode "Visitors from Beyond the Stars" of the TV series The Time Tunnel (1966-1967).
The episodes can be watched here:



The Time tunnel used scenes from many previous movies for various events in the past that the time travelers found themselves in. 
The episode "Visitors from Beyond the Stars" used exterior shots of a space ship from Roger Corman's movie War of the Satellites (1958) that Irwin Allen also used in episodes of his series Lost in Space.  The aliens come to raid Earth for protein to feed their planet.  Since they land at Mullins, Arizona in 1885 the episode uses sets, props, and costumes from western movies.  And the people of Mullins, Arizona also face danger from raiding Apaches.
There is a scene, obviously taken from a movie, where Apaches wipe out a cavalry troop.
I would describe the scene as taking place in a desert with big boulders and sparse shrubs and tall reddish mesas in the background.  The cavalry and the Indians (not necessarily Apaches in the movie it is taken from) ride around.  The cavalry dismount and form a circle.  There are wide shots of the Indians riding in a circle around them and closer shots of the soldiers shooting but no close ups.  When the soldiers all fall the Indians rush in on them.
It could be an inexpensive version of Custer's Last Stand, though I thought that I have seen every version of Custer's Last Stand filmed in color by 1966
Any big fan of westerns should be able to identify the great cavalry and Indians battle scene in the episode "Massacre" as coming from the movies Pony Soldier (1952), Siege at Red River (1954), and Pawnee (1957), and originally filmed for Buffalo Bill (1944).
And so any big fan of westerns should be able to identify the movie that the battle between the Apaches and the cavalry in "Visitors from Beyond the Stars" comes from.
